# Windows 10 - OpenSSH Server - Operation timed out

Tags: ssh, openssh

I followed [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse) instructions.

- The firewall rule "OpenSSH-Server-In-TCP" is present and enabled.

  - The command: `New-NetFirewallRule -Name sshd -DisplayName 'OpenSSH Server (sshd)' -Enabled True -Direction Inbound -Protocol TCP -Action Allow -LocalPort 22`
- `sshd` is running
- Port 22 is `LISTENING`

And yet I get `ssh: connect to host MY_IP port 22: Operation timed out` when trying to remote in from another device outside the network.

Comment: Did you find the answer useful?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. General networking questions should be posted to [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Answer (score 6):

You have to debug where is the hindrance.

Depending on whether you have access to the server, check if the *Status* of the service is *Running* (*Windows key* -> *Services*). I saw it bear the names `sshd` or `Open SSH` (if you don't find it under one or the other name, check the whole list of services just in case).

[image]

Then check if you can `ssh` from a (DOS or PowerShell) command prompt within the same server, with `ssh localhost`, or even try with another user.
Try also `ssh MY_IP` from the same server.

Please report back results.

Comment: If i run `ssh localhost` it works. If I run `ssh MY_IP` with the IP explicitly (while on the same network) I get `ssh: connect to host MY_IP port 22: Connection refused`. And when off the network I get a timeout

Comment: @Hello - What happens if you `ssh MY_IP` from the same server? It should work.

Comment: `ssh: connect to host MY_IP port 22: Connection refused`

Comment: @Hello - What do you see with `Get-NetFirewallRule -Name *ssh*`?
Do you see the service running as asked above?

Comment: @Hello - And about the other question?